# Getting data after terraform azurerm template deployment

Tags: terraform, azure-resource-manager, terraform-provider-azure

I am deploying my infra with terraform, but for AKS I use ARM templating because it has some features that are not in TF yet.
So in my tf template I have the following resource defined to deploy an ARM template:

```
resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "k8s" {
  name                  = "${var.environment}-aks-deployment"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.kubernetes.name}"

  parameters              = {
    workspaceResourceId = "${azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.k8s-law.id}"
    aksClusterName      = "fntm-k8s-${var.environment}"
    subnetKubernetes    = "${azurerm_subnet.kubernetes.id}"
    servicePrincipal    = "${azuread_service_principal.k8s_sp.application_id}"
    clientSecret        = "${random_string.sp_password.result}"
    clientAppID         = "${var.clientAppID}"
    serverAppID         = "${var.serverAppID}"
    tenantID            = "${var.tenant_id}"
    serverAppSecret     = "${var.serverAppSecret}"
  }

  template_body         = "${file("kubernetes/azuredeploy.json")}"

    deployment_mode = "Incremental"
}
```

The deployment of the cluster goes fine, but after that I need to get data from the AKS cluster which will be used by a different module.
If I use the data resource for AKS it tries to get the cluster data before it is deployed. So the below part doesn't work.

```
data "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "kubernetes" {
  name                = "fntm-k8s-${var.environment}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.kubernetes.name}"
}
```

I thought maybe a depends_on but that is not supported in the data resource.

Anybody maybe an idea how I can get the data attribute node_resource_group from the AKS cluster with output? Or any other thoughts/solutions?

```
output "k8s_resource_group" {
  value = "${lookup(azurerm_template_deployment.k8s.outputs, "?????")}"
}
```

Comment: Can you also share your `azuredeploy.json` file?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR 

pastebin.com/cFMJfmDy

Comment: I tried some more to get it to work:

I added this output to my json:
    "outputs": {
        "aksClusterName": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[parameters('aksClusterName')]"
        }
    }

Comment: And then in my cluster.tf I did this:

output "aksClusterName" {
  value = "${lookup(azurerm_template_deployment.k8s.outputs, "aksClusterName")}"
  depends_on = ["azurerm_template_deployment.k8s"]
}

data "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "kubernetes" {
  name                = "fntm-k8s-${var.environment}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.kubernetes.name}"
}

Comment: But then i get the error that managed resource "output" has not been declared.

Comment: I don't think you can use the data to get the resource which created in the same terraform file. You just can use the data to get the existing resource when you apply the terraform file.

Comment: Tried several things but I am not able to get it working. With the new version 1.32.0 the autoscaling and av zones are available so arm is not needed anymore for me.
Would still like to know how to get it to work though.

Answer (score 0):

In your azuredeploy.json use this for the output:

```
"outputs": {
    "aksClusterName": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[parameters('aksClusterName')]"
    }
}
```

And in your tf file use:

```
output "aksClusterName" {
  value = "${azurerm_template_deployment.k8s.outputs["aksClusterName"]}"
}

data "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "kubernetes" {
  name                = ""
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.kubernetes.name}"
}

output "k8s_resource_group" {
  value = "${data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.kubernetes.node_resource_group}"
}
```

Comment: this output can be used in other modules if necessary.